# Eclipse formatter to allow aligning ='s and Javadoc tab

Tags: java, eclipse, formatter

I am working with an Eclipse formatter and I want the following code formatting. Note how the JavaDoc and `=`'s are aligned.

What I want:

```
/**
 * Description.
 *
 * @param alpha this is what alpha does
 * @param beta  this is what beta does
 * @param gamma this is what gamma does
 * @param delta this is what delta does
 */
public Foo(Bar alpha, Bar beta, Bar gamma, Bar delta) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.beta  = beta;
    this.gamma = gamma;
    this.delta = delta;
}
```

What eclipse formats:

```
/**
 *
 * @param alpha this is what alpha does
 * @param beta this is what beta does
 * @param gamma this is what gamma does
 * @param delta this is what delta does
 */
public Foo(Bar alpha, Bar beta, Bar gamma, Bar delta) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.beta = beta;
    this.gamma = gamma;
    this.delta = delta;
}
```

Does anyone know if this is possible?

If it is not possible to do this automatically, is it possible to have the formatter ignore the whitespace on those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Jindent](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/jindent-source-code-formatter-javacc) plugin which is available for the most common IDEs:
    Eclipse, Netbeans, JDeveloper, IntelliJ IDEA, JBuilder

This will preserve the formatting for your code

```
/**
 * Description.
 *
 * @param alpha this is what alpha does
 * @param beta  this is what beta does
 * @param gamma this is what gamma does
 * @param delta this is what delta does
 */
public Foo(Bar alpha, Bar beta, Bar gamma, Bar delta) {
    this.alpha = alpha;
    this.beta  = beta;
    this.gamma = gamma;
    this.delta = delta;
}

//~ Formatted by Jindent --- http://www.jindent.com
```

Unlike Eclipse's default formatting command <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, you need to use 
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> to format your code using `Jindent`.

It only adds a comment at the end of the code which you would have to manually remove.

---

Update: To install it, simply drag the icon over your Eclipse Window
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks too specific to have a built in solution. There might be a plugin to help with that.

> If it is not possible to do this automatically, is it possible to have the formatter ignore the whitespace on those lines?

Yes, with `@formatter` tags.

1. Go to `Windows > Preferences`.
2. From there `Java > Code Style > Formatter > Edit`
3. Choose the `On/Off Tags` tab and check the `Enable` checkbox.
4. Apply them to your code:

   ```
   //@formatter:off
   /**
   * Description.
   *
   * @param alpha this is what alpha does
   * @param beta  this is what beta does
   * @param gamma this is what gamma does
   * @param delta this is what delta does
   */
   //@formatter:on
   public Foo(Bar alpha, Bar beta, Bar gamma, Bar delta) {
       this.alpha = alpha;
       this.beta  = beta;
       this.gamma = gamma;
       this.delta = delta;
   }
   ```

Alternatively, if you want to disable all Javadoc formatting:

3. Choose the `Comments` tag and uncheck the `Enable Javadoc comment formatting` checkbox.

The following is not what you want because it adds new lines, but might be close enough for you since it aligns the parameters descriptions with each other:

```
/**
 * Description.
 *
 * @param alpha
 *            this is what alpha does
 * @param beta
 *            this is what beta does
 * @param gamma
 *            this is what gamma does
 * @param delta
 *            this is what delta does
 */
```

This is achieved by:

3. Choose the `Comments` tag and check the `Indent Javadoc tags`, (optionally) `Indent description after @param` and `New line after @param tags` checkboxes.

Comment: This is alright, but do you have an example of a plugin which would handle this?

Comment: @screenmutt No, never had the need for one myself.